# Another Failure on HttpWebrequest with inner exception Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream

Tags: c#, ssl

I know this has been asked before but the solutions suggested in those cases have not work for me. I have a simple console app that scrapes data from a website. Last night they updated their security settings so my code doesn't work anymore.

Here Is the code snippet I'm trying to use:

```
try
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
    var request2 = WebRequest.Create("https://www.eex-transparency.com/") as HttpWebRequest;
    request2.Method = "GET";
    request2.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
    request2.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-gb");
    request2.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
    request2.Headers.Add("DNT", "1");
    request2.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko";
    request2.Host = "www.eex-transparency.com";
    request2.KeepAlive = true;
    request2.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");
    request2.Proxy = ProxyFactory.GetWebProxy();
    using (var response = request2.GetResponse())
    {}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ Console.WriteLine(ex);}
```

There error I receive is:

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed becausethe remote party has closed the transport stream.
>
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocol
>   Request asyncRequest)
>
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, A
>   syncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>
> at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>
> at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
>
> at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>
> at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That URL supports TLS v1.1 / v1.2 only, try adjusting your SecurityProtocol mask accordingly

Comment: Thanks @AlexK. that worked, for my education how did you find out the url only supports v1.1/1.2? For anyone who comes across this tls11 and tls12 are available in framework 4.5 and higher.

Comment: Your welcome.  I ran the URL through https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com/

Comment: @Alex K. Ok thanks one for me to use in the future.

Comment: If you fixed the issue you can post what you did as an answer then accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This specific url only supports TLS version 1.1 and 1.2. Added the below for the code to work:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

Make sure you are using Framework 4.5 or higher

Comment: Hi @Elias, I have a function for this, will you please guide me to where I have to put this code?

I am facing the same problem.
TIA

Comment: @HardikMasalawala place it where you have your httpwebrequest code e.g.
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    var resp = req.GetResponse();

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.

Answer (score -1):

Do one thing it will work

```
request2.KeepAlive = false;
```